# The interior of a manifold with a boundary is a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am reading Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* and attempting to prove the following proposition:

> **Proposition 2.58.** *If $M$ is an n-dimensional manifold with a boundary, then $\textrm{Int} M$ is an open subset of $M,$ which is itself an n-dimensional manifold without boundary.*

Where manifolds with a boundary are defined in terms of charts mapped to open sets in $\mathbb{H}^n = \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times [0, \infty).$ I need to prove this without using the invariance of the boundary (i.e. that the manifold boundary and interior are disjoint.

My attempt so far involved the construction of charts $(U_i, \varphi_i)$ that cover $M$ and the identification of points mapped to $\partial\mathbb{H}^n$ with $\partial M;$ however, I can't use $\textrm{Int} M = M \setminus \partial M$ without invoking the invariance of boundary. I would prefer hints or partial answers suggesting how I should proceed to full proofs.

Comment: Why was the tag changed to differential geometry? I'm somewhat new to the study of manifolds but I believe differential geometry focuses on the study of smooth or Riemannian manifolds. My question is about topological manifolds so isn't algebraic topology more fitting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to give a hint to this problem without giving the whole thing away. By definition, $\text{Int} M$ is the subset of all $x \in M$ for which *there exists* a chart $(U_i,\phi_i)$ such that $x \in U_i$ and such that $\phi_i(U_i) \subset \mathbb R^{n-1} \times (0,\infty)$. This *existence* property is clearly also true for every $y \in U_i$, using the exact same chart $(U_i,\phi_i)$, and therefore $U_i \subset \text{Int}(M)$.

Comment: Oh. Thereby showing that Int M is open since every point has an open neighborhood, and locally Euclidean since each of those neighborhoods has an image contained in the open upper half space. Correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your help Lee

Comment: @Lee Mosher Hi professor in Lee's book, the interior chart is only defined to let $\phi_i(U_i)$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ not as halfplane i.e. $\phi_i(U_i) \subset \mathbb R^{n-1} \times (0,\infty)$ as you did here.  But it does not matter since we can always translate $\phi_i(U_i)$ into halfplane Correct?